# OpenGL invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct GLUquadric’

Tags: opengl

In the code segment below I'm trying to use glunewquadric() but I keep getting an error that says "invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct GLUquadric’."  As far as I can tell I've done everything that I should have.  What am I doing wrong?

```
GLUquadricObj* quad;

glClearDepth(1);
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, LightPosition);

quad = gluNewQuadric();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a OpenGL problem. Basically your compiler tells you, that it doesn't know how `GLUquadric` looks like (incomplete type). You could use it as a pointer, but this error indicates that you're trying to dereference it somewhere.

Either you forgot to include a header, containing the struct definition (in your case maybe `GL/glu.h`), or you tried to define a `GLUquadric` variable that isn't a pointer.

---

BTW: GLU isn't part of OpenGL.